# HTML select element with fixed width and scrollbars

Tags: html, css, select, scrollbar

This is probably a basic CSS question, but I am not fluent in CSS and just seem to be going in circles.

Here's what I have in English: I have a fixed width select element of 400px. The text for each of the options does not fit in that 400px width. I don't get a horizontal scroll bar, it just cuts off the text. How do I get the scroll bar?

Here's what I have in HTML/CSS:

```
<div>
  <select style="width=400px">
    <option>this text is too wide to fit and gets cut off.....</option>
    ...
  </select>
</div>
```

I've tried the overflow property, but I'm either using it incorrectly or it doesn't work on the select element.

How do I get the horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Form elements are notoriously difficult to style.

For your width setting, you have a small typo. You need

```
<select style="width: 400px">
```

Otherwise, I think horizontal scrollbars can't be achieved using a normal `select` element. You would have to resort to a JavaScript based alternative like [**SexyCombo**](http://vladimir-k.blogspot.com/2009/02/sexy-combo-jquery-plugin.html), which may be customizable to have a scroll bar. More options here: [**11 jQuery Plugins to Enhance HTML Dropdowns**](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/)

Comment: sorry, the "width=" is a typo and is not in my actual code. Is it possible to make the select really big to fit all of the text, and make the surrounding div a fixed width/height that has scrollbars?

Comment: @schmimd04 That should be possible by giving the surrounding DIV a fixed size and `overflow: auto;` However, it will bring additional issues, such as the arrow button being hidden as well. But try it out.

Comment: Just don't give the select a "width" and it will be as big as the longest option. Then surround the select with a DIV that e.g. has '"width: 400px; overflow: auto;"'

Comment: There is indeed a very simple solution to this. Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnkEG/17/)

Answer (score 3):

1. it should be `<select style="width: 400px;">` (not "`width=`")
2. a regular HTML-select doesn't have a scrollbar, no matter what you do :)

Comment: `2.a select doesn't have a scrollbar, no matter what you do :)` - So how do you handle multiple selections?  `<select multiple><option>Hello1</option><option>Hello2</option><option>Hello3</option></select>`

Comment: @Andy no fair, `select multiple` is a different beast :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using inline css syntax
you should use style="width: 400px;"

And 
if you have use multiple selection you just use

```
<select multiple style="width: 400px;">
```